# Laravel Blade HTML::style and HTML::script remove newline

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-4

Hey guys I just want to ask how to remove the Blade newline when using this code

**Blade**

```
{{ HTML::style('packages/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css') }}
{{ HTML::style('contents/css/master.css') }}
```

**HTML**

```
<link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/packages/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">

<link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/contents/css/master.css">
```

I want to make the HTML result like this

```
<link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/packages/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
<link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/contents/css/master.css">
```

Thank you! :D

Comment: what difference does it make?

Comment: The difference is that there are no newline after each link tag.

Comment: difference in _function_ or _purpose_?

Comment: Its nice when minimizing newline or whitespace in the view to load the page a little fast maybe? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing PHP_EOL inside public function style and public function script will remove the newline in each link tag/script tag.